# How to make an image link to a product page in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to make a product image link to the product page in magento. I have done this before with similar code but, for some reason this time it refuses to work. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

```
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25%; padding-right: 15px;  > 
<p><a href="<?php echo $_related->getProductUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this-      >helper('catalog/image')->init($_related, 'small_image')->resize(125) ?>" width="125"   height="125" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_related->getName()) ?>" /></a></p> 
<h5><a href="<?php echo $_related->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo 
$this->htmlEscape($_related->getName()) ?></a></h5> 
</td>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'refuses to work'?

Comment: What class is $_related ? a product or other ? It may just be an element of a product collection, with a addAttributeToSelect not containing the url.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested below code which works for me

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>">
<img class="product-image" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(130, 170) ?>" width="130" height="170" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" />
</a>
```